# How to add multiple projects into a Single repository in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am trying to add multiple projects into a single repository in Bitbucket, but after commiting when I pushed to the origin master it just added the empty folders. No subfolders and files have been added. I have followed below steps,

1. From the main folder, `git init`
2. `git remote add origin gitrepository` name
3. `git add --all`
4. `git commit -m "initial commit"`
5. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 3):

That would happen if those project folders are themselves [nested git repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216758/6309).

In that case, the content of those nested repos would be ignored: see "[How to commit a git repo into a git repo (not submodule)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18786198/6309)".

You could try and "[merge nested git repo into parent repo, retaining history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14839653/6309)".

Or you could declare those nested repo as submodule.
(as in "[Creating Git Submodules out of existing repository and reflecting parent changes to the child repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517881/6309)")